# rerturning response of an ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am trying to check if an email exists in the db but the function doesn't return a value.

This is the code:

```
function checkemail(email)
{
    var returnVal = "";
    if (email.indexOf("@") != -1 && email.indexOf(".") != -1)
    {
        $.post( "registreren.php?email=" + email, function( response ) {
            if(response == 1) { returnVal = 1; }
            if(response == 2) { returnVal = 2; }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        returnVal = 3;
    }//email

    return returnVal;

}
```

EDIT: email is send as a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous function, use callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I short, *You can not return values from `ajax` calls as it is asynchronous by nature, the statement `return value` executes before*

To address such cases, use `callback`, a function accepted as argument and which is executed when `response` is been received (*when asynchronous action is completed*).

Try this:

```js
function checkemail(email, callback) {
  var returnVal = "";
  if (email.indexOf("@") != -1 && email.indexOf(".") != -1) {
    $.post("registreren.php?email=" + email, function(response) {
      callback(response);
    });
  } else {
    callback(3);
  }
}
checkemail('abc@xyz.com', function(val) {
  alert(val);
});

checkemail('INVALID_EMAIL', function(val) {
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something simple like below

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'registreren.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'email': email},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 1)
            {
               returnVal = 1; 
            }
            else
            {
               returnVal = 3; 
            }
        }
    });
```

instead of

```
$.post( "registreren.php?email=" + email, function( response ) {
            if(response == 1) { returnVal = 1; }
            if(response == 2) { returnVal = 2; }
    });
```

Comment: All you've done is swap the shorthand for the longhand.  It doesn't address the problem at all.

Comment: doesn't matter if it resolves the issue..and by the way it has more options you can pass.

Comment: It doesn't resolve the issue though, and if you don't need to pass those options, that's what the shorthand is there for.